# convert unsigned char * to json, jsonspp C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, jsoncpp

I have unsigned char array holding data, I want to store this into a Json object. How can it be done? Using jsoncpp and C++11.
the statement

```
rootL1["CurrentValue"] = userInfo->hashCred;
```

does not work, in turn it is stored as bool in json instead of the unsigned data.

Comment: one way of doing it is to convert the data to json array & vice versa

Answer (score 2):

If you can look into documentation of jsoncpp [Value](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html) class (I assume `rootL1` is of this type, and `operator[]` returns the same type), you will see that there is no `unsigned char*` conversion constructor which would accept your `userInfo->hashCred` array. There is one constructor which accepts `const char*` but there is no implicit conversion from `unsigned char*` to `const char*`, the closest one is implicit conversion of pointer to bool which is choosen in your case.

The solution should be to use conversion constructor which accepts `const char*`. You should think why you need `unsigned char*` in the first place, maybe you can use an array of type `char`? If you cant then you can try casting `unsigned char*` to `char*`:

```
rootL1["CurrentValue"] = reinterpret_cast<char *>(userInfo->hashCred)
```

but this can cause all sorts of problems depending on what you are actually storing in your array and also what jsoncpp is doing under the hood with this data.

I would suggest you treat your hashCred as binary data and uuencode it to `char` array. Then store it in jsoncpp Value. For details look into here: [Binary data JSONCPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812053/binary-data-jsoncpp)

In [jsoncpp test code](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/96d32b37eac518147f3d733012a6c28db3720328/src/test_lib_json/main.cpp) you can also find some examples of how to store binary data as values.